# Setting translated messages in flash messages using jmsTranslationBundle

Tags: translation

I cannot seem to find a way to set a translated text in a flash message.
I am using JSMTranslationbundle for translations.

Here is my best shot.

/** @Desc("Verification successfully requested") */       $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('message.success', $this->get('translator')->trans('checklist_instance.verifiaction_success.'));

But it just returns my key in the template.
Any ideas?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the annotation directly before the translation call?

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set(
    /** @Desc("Verification successfully requested") */
    $this->get('translator')->trans('checklist_instance.verification_success')
);
```

It could also be an issue with the JMSTranslationBundle if you use a very very old version (< feb 2012).

*Side note: You had a typo in the translation key (e.g., verifiaction instead of verification).*